# Unable to verify this domain because it is used elsewhere in Office 365

Tags: azure, office365, adfs

To whom it may concern.

We run ADFS with local AD syncing to Azure AD for SSO with Azure and Office 365.

We recently moved our Azure subscription to a new account. We were instructed to add the AD for the domain again. There is a persisting issue that we cannot verify the domain. Due to this issue we cannot access certain sites/services with delegated accounts, i.e. only the microsoft account that is the owner can access the services.

The error when trying to verify the domain with `Confirm-MsolDomain -DomainName cognadev.com`﻿ is﻿

> "Unable to verify this domain because it is used elsewhere in Office
>   365. Remove the verified domain from the other service before adding it here."

How can I see where else the domain is used?
How can I remove the domain from where it is used, without losing mailboxes etc?

Please advise.

Comment: Update: We managed to get access to the original account that the subscription was created on. 
Turns out that the AD was still active on that account on the custom domain we are using and this is what has been causing issues. We removed all the user accounts and groups from the Azure AD for the account.
This allowed the custom domain to be deleted from the old account and then we were able to verify the domain on the new account. We are still facing an issue of not being able to move users from the onmicrosoft.com to the custom domain.

Comment: ...and then we find this morning that the users are now syncing to Azure AD correctly and linking to Office 365. Issue now is that the MS Online Business Essentials license had not moved to the new service account. Bummer. Now we are faced with the message:
`Your mailbox has been temporarily moved on Microsoft Exchange server. A temporary mailbox exists, but it might not have all of your previous data.`

Comment: Turns out we needed to migrate all users to _new_ mailboxes and import their old email from .pst files. What a mission.

Answer (score 0):

We had to do two things to get everything working again:

1. We removed all the user accounts and groups from the Azure AD for the account. This allowed the custom domain to be deleted from the old account and then we were able to verify the domain on the new account.
2. We migrated all users to new mailboxes and imported their old email from .pst files.

Quite a mission.

Lesson learned.